# How to make caption of a subfigure wider after scaling the figure?

Tags: floats, captions, subcaption

i wanna scale (a) similar to (c)
unfortunatelly, the caption is scaled too
how can i make the caption of (c) wider (similar to caption of (a))?
thank you

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,left=25mm,right=25mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{subfigure}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\subfigure[this is a text this is a text this is a text this is a textthis is a text this is a text this is a text this is a text this is a text this is a text]
{\includegraphics[width=0.46\textwidth]{picture.ps}}\hspace{1cm}%\hfill
\subfigure[this is a text this is a text this is a text this is a textthis is a text this is a text this is a text this is a text this is a text this is a text]
{\includegraphics[width=0.46\textwidth]{picture.ps}}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\subfigure[this is a text this is a text this is a text this is a textthis is a text this is a text this is a text this is a text this is a text this is a text]
{\includegraphics[scale=0.25]{picture.ps}}\hspace{1cm}%\hfill
\subfigure[this is a text this is a text this is a text this is a textthis is a text this is a text this is a text this is a text this is a text this is a text]
{\includegraphics[width=0.46\textwidth]{picture.ps}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

i add two picts: figure (a) and (b), and figure (c) and (d)

[image: pic 1]

[image: pic2]

summary: the figures should be c and d but the captions should be a(!) and d

additional question: figures are on the same line

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: edited - see above

Comment: You can try with the `subcaption` package, which allows you to specify the width of the box that contains the subfigure.  That way you can set them to be equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in my comments, you can try with the [`subcaption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) package which allows you to specify the width of the box that contains the subfigure. That way you can set them to be equal.  E.g.:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\linewidth}
        \centering
            \includegraphics[scale=1]{demo}
            \caption{A lot of text here for the caption so it goes over the line break}
        \label{fig:SkeletalTissue}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\linewidth}
        \centering
            \includegraphics[scale=1]{demo}
            \caption{A lot of text here for the caption so it goes over the line break}
        \label{fig:CardiacTissue}
    \end{subfigure}
    \\
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\linewidth}
        \centering
            \includegraphics[width=2cm]{demo}
            \caption{A lot of text here for the caption so it goes over the line break}
        \label{fig:SmoothTissue}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\linewidth}
        \centering
            \includegraphics[scale=1]{demo}
            \caption{A lot of text here for the caption so it goes over the line break}
        \label{fig:OtherTissue}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Types of Muscular Tissue}
    \label{fig:MuscularTissue}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Which produces

[image]

Comment: hi mario works great - tnx a lot

Comment: @user60519 If any answer on this site works for you, please don't forget to upvote and mark as answered :) (keeps things tidy and helps future user to find an answer quickly)

Comment: i would do - unfortunately it says Vote Up requires 15 reputation

Comment: i have an additional question:
if the caption length is different in any figure (e.g., (a) has a caption with 2 lines, (b) with 4 lines and so on)
than the figures above are not on the same line - how can i change this? ... see screenshot above ("additional question: figures are on the same line")

Comment: instead of option `[b]` try `[t]`

Comment: mario you are absolute right! tnx ... and only a few reputations away to give you an +1 ;)